# integrating rails and backbone routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I'm having trouble triggering a 'hangman' function when I go to a route

application.js

```
var init = function(){
  console.log("init called");      #logged
  var router = new Router();
  console.log(router);
  Backbone.history.start();
};
```

When I inspect the 'router' variable in console.log(router), it shows that the hangman function is created on the router object

```
child
__proto__: ctor
constructor: function (){ return parent.apply(this, arguments); }
hangman: function () {
routes: Object
/hangman: "hangman"
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

However, when I navigate to localhost:3000/hangman, the alert is not getting called.  Can you suggest what I might be doing wrong. I'm using backbone in a Rails app.  I don't quite get how Backbone understands the Rails route, as localhost:3000/hangman is defined in my rails router file. I thought I might have to do localhost:3000/hangman/#hangman in order to activate the backbone route (with the rails route being irrelevant) but that didn't work either.

router.js

```
$(function() {

  window.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
    '/hangman' : 'hangman'
  },

    hangman: function() {
      console.log("hangman called");      #never logged
      alert("hangman");
  }

  });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [fine `Router#extend` manual](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-extend):

> **extend** `Backbone.Router.extend(properties, [classProperties])`
>
> [...] Note that you'll want to avoid using a leading slash in your route definitions:

You might be interested in the [`pushState` option](http://backbonejs.org/#History-start) as well:

> **start** `Backbone.history.start([options])`
>   [...]
>   To indicate that you'd like to use HTML5 `pushState` support in your application, use `Backbone.history.start({pushState: true})`.

So fix your routes first:

```
routes: {
    'hangman' : 'hangman' // No more leading slash.
}
```

And then use `pushState: true` to get `/hangman` (rather than `/#hangman`) to work:

Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true });

Comment: as soon as I saw the word "fine" i knew who was answering this question. btw, you have to have a certain level of intelligence and experience to apply information from manuals, and I'm  "mu(ch) too short" on both

Comment: That is one of my favorite openings :)